# How to connect Firebase realtime database to my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect firebase realtime database to my project.

Below is my code.

```
val TAG = "MainActivity"
val testRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         //skipped other stuff
         //it's about bottom navigation view
    testRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                error.toException().printStackTrace()
            }
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val message = snapshot.value.toString()
                Log.d(TAG,message)
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
         })
     }
```

And when I add my app on firebase project, following the instruction, I added

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
```

to my project build gradle

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
```

to my app module build gradle. and also added jason file.

When I change value in firebase database, if there is nothing wrong, it should toast a text about the changed value. But nothing happens.

Also a notice like below comes up when I use the dependency above.

```
Kotlin library {0} was compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin
```

As it says, I updated the kotlin plugin but it still doesn't disappear and shows 'No updates found'

[image: My firebase database looks like this]

Above image is part of my firebase database

How should I do?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, but "nothing happens" is really hard to help with. Did you already set breakpoints inside `onCancelled` and `onDataChange` and run in the debugger? When you do this, which of these breakpoints (if any) gets triggered?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry that I am a beginner. Im not sure what a breakpoint is. I see that running the app by 'debug app' has no problem, but the app doesn't toast a message when I change the 'test' value in the database.

Comment: There's no need to be sorry about being a beginner. We're here to help. --- Since it's not immediately obvious (to me) where the problem in the code is, I want to help you learn how to debug your code. Right now you're focusing on the **final result** and that it isn't what you want. Debugging is finding out what is the **first thing** that your code does that isn't what you expect it to do. To learn how to get started with that, have a look at: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug, which also covers working with breakpoints.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your advice. I'llstudy about it !